# Updating data on rows deleted event

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom page with a form and a grid. When a row from a grid is deleted, I want to update some other rows. I am therefore handling the rowdeleted event. I confirmed (through debugging) that the event is firing correctly and that the data is being updated correctly.

The only issue I have is that the screen still shows the old values. My delete row correctly disappears but the other rows do not get updated.

For each row that I change, I am calling the Update method of the Data View. However, this still does not refresh the user interface. 
Interesting, if I save, all my changes get correctly updated to the database. Which confirms that this is a UI isssue.

Is there any additional step that I need to perform to refresh the user interface? Or should I just avoid doing updates in Row Deleted event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To guarantee constant optimal performance level, in the end of a roundtrip grids in Acumatica only update currently selected record. This behavior is by default. In case you insert/update/delete other records in the same grid within an event handler or an action delegate, it's always necessary to call `View.RequestRefresh()` to force the grid to update its entire content instead of only the selected record.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by calling View.RequestRefresh(). However, I am not sure whether this is a standard practice. But I did find it used in several places in the Acumatica code

Comment: This is standard practice,but as I know before `View.RequestRefresh()` you should call `View.Clear()` also.